# Adding items to the top of a dynamic listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am new to android and not a killer in programming. I am trying to implement a dynamic listview in which items must be added to the top, rather than getting added to the bottom by default. Is there a way to achieve this? Below is the code I used to create a dynamic listview. Please help!

```
private void populateListView() {

            Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
                    {DBadapter.KEY_FIELD1,DBadapter.KEY_FIELD2};
            int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                    {R.id.field1,R.id.field2};

            SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                            this,
                            R.layout.inner_list_view,
                            cursor,
                            fromFieldNames,
                            toViewIDs
                            );
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleList);
            myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
            myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListViews` support stacking the items from the bottom.  You can either set it in the XML with [android:stackFromBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:stackFromBottom) or you can set it programmatically by invoking [setStackFromBottom(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom(boolean)).

I don't understand the 2nd part of your question.

Comment: Even if I use StackFromBottom, a new item is getting added on at the bottom. For ex, I dynamically added a listitem A to my empty list and then on adding listitem B, it gets added at the bottom. I need listitem B to get added at the top. This is very similar like saving notes in a notes application. If you save a new note, it gets added only at the top right?

Comment: Why not just retrieve the data for the cursor in reverse order?

Comment: Will this work? Can I use this query in my databaseAdapter Class. myDb.query(true, MY_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_FIELD1, KEY_FIELD2}, null, null, null, null, COL_FIELD1+" DESC", null);

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "insert" method. It allows you to define position to add new items

```
    myCursorAdapter.insert(newItem, 0);
```

Use a loop if you have multiple elements